# Increase amount of item search result via ebay API Python

Tags: python, ebay-api

I got a basic script to connect with ebay API and search for keyword items. The script works fine, but unfortunatelly, it searches only the first 100 items, how to increase amount of the search results ?

```
from ebaysdk.finding import Connection as finding
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Keywords = 'Ford'
api = finding(appid='APP ID', config_file=None)
api_request = { 'keywords': Keywords, 'outputSelector': 'SellerInfo' }

response = api.execute('findItemsByKeywords', api_request)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
totalentries = int(soup.find('totalentries').text)
items= soup.find_all('item')
```

I finally sorted this one out. The paginationInput is actually a dictionary in it self, which was a bit messing with me. Also for some reason it's more useful to use findItemsAdvanced  instead of findItemsByKeywords .

```
Keywords = product
    api = finding(appid='APP_ID', config_file=None)
    api_request = { 'keywords': product,'outputSelector': 'SellerInfo' ,  'categoryId': ['33034'],  'paginationInput':{'entriesPerPage':100, 'pageNumber':1} }


    response = api.execute('findItemsAdvanced', api_request)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ebay is probably [paginating](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/types/PaginationType.html), that means that they are splitting their response by a number of entries for each page.

Their response to a query should have the current page number and the total number of pages, you will need to request all the following pages you are interested in.

Comment: yes thatm was the case. Thanks. The paginationInput is a dictionary it self, which seemed to be the case this time

Answer (score 0):

This is documented on the [page for `findItemsByKeywords`](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/callref/finditemsbykeywords.html#page).

Add a `paginationInput.pageNumber` parameter to your API request parameters, maybe something like

```py
from ebaysdk.finding import Connection
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Keywords = "Ford"
api = Connection(appid="APP ID", config_file=None)

items = []

for page in range(1, 11):
    api_request = {
        "keywords": Keywords,
        "outputSelector": "SellerInfo",
        "paginationInput.pageNumber": page,
    }
    response = api.execute("findItemsByKeywords", api_request)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
    totalentries = int(soup.find("totalentries").text)
    items.extend(soup.find_all("item"))

print(items)
```

Comment: i had to add the paginationInput which is actually an dictionary on its own and looks like this 'paginationInput':{'entriesPerPage':100, 'pageNumber':num}, and change "findItemsByKeywords"  for 'findItemsAdvanced'